# Python nested while loop, different output in c++

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops, flags

I am trying to learn python and some basic nested loops algorithm.

Supposed output should be:
`x1, x2, x3, 1, 2, 3, x1, x2, x3 ......`

```
flag = 0
x = 0
y = 0
while(True):   
    
    while(flag == 0):
        x += 1;
        print("x", end= "")
        print(x)
        time.sleep(1)
        if (x >= 3):
            flag = 0
            break;
    y += 1
    print(y)
    time.sleep(1)
    if (y >= 3):
        flag = 0
        x = 0
        y = 0
```

What I get: `x1, x2, x3, 1, x4, 2, x5, 3, x1, x2, x3, 1, 2, 3 ...`

I tried doing the same code to c++ and I get correct output. Did I overlooked something in my code  like proper indentions or my code is just wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: After `if (x >= 3):` `flag` should be anything but `0`. Right now, the x printing while runs again after the first y print.

Comment: Thanks, seems like I overlooked that part while in my c++ it was ```flag = 1```. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `flag` is always `0`. You need to set it something else after you've done your `x` work.

```
    if (x >= 3):
        flag = 1
        break
```

But then we wouldn't increment variables in a `while` if something can be iterated with a `for` instead.

```
import time

while True:    
    for x in range(1,4):
        print(f"x{x}")
        time.sleep(1)

    for y in range(1,4):
        print(f"{y}")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Iterating a range object manages the `x` and `y` values for you.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually trying out something for my raspberry + arduino serial communication project.